# Spark pipeline optimizations :Coalesce over filtered dataset

Tags: csv, apache-spark, out-of-memory, pyspark

I'm afraid about what is doing spark (1.5.1) in background when I filter a dataset and them performs a coalesce. I want to generate a CSV file with a subset of my dataset. To do that I execute:

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('...') # huge dataset
df_ids = sqlContext.read.parquet('...') # dataframe with the wanted IDs

df = df.join(df_ids, 'id', 'inner') # keep only rows with wanted ids from df
df = df.dropna().filter( df.Ti % 5 == 0 ) # only 2 in 10 rows
```

Now, if I do the coalesce and save as csv, the process fails because it can't reserve enought memory:

```
df.coalesce(1)\
  .write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
  .mode('overwrite')\
  .option('header', 'true')\
  .save('/tmp/my.csv')
```

Instead of that, if I save the dataframe and then load it and do the coalesce, it works like magic:

```
df.write.parquet('/tmp/df.parquet')
sqlContext.read.parquet('/tmp/df.parquet').coalesce(1)\
    .write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
    .mode('overwrite')\
    .option('header', 'true')\
    .save('/tmp/my.csv')
```

It seems to me that spark is doing the `coalesce(1)` before any other operation so the whole dataset can't be allocated in memory. Is it really happening? Can I avoid that?

Thank you!

Comment: if you are reading everything to one partition, what's the need for spark then ? `coalesce(1)` is an anti-pattern in spark. This is counter optimization

Comment: I just want to generate a small subset of the full data and spark has the enough libraries to do that. However, I'm having this problem also when I do a data repartition after filtering. It seems that is moving all the data instead of the filtered data